# Magento 2 newsletter subscription redirection to custom page

Tags: magento2, newsletter, redirection

**Default behavior**:

When I subscribed to newsletter then it displayed the success message in the same page itself.

**What I want is**:

When the customer or guest user subscribe to the newsletter I want them to be redirected to a custom page(cms page).In other words, I just want to display a separate thank you page after clicking "submit" button.

So, how can I achieve this?

<sup>**Magento 2.2.6**</sup>

Comment: You have to rewrite a controller then you change the redirect, or simply with an observer

Comment: @PRINCE I don't know which controller file should be edited? So, can you tell me that?

Comment: `Controller/newsletter/subscriber/newAction.php`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to change the subscribe functionality and only want to redirect to a different page, you can simply do this by writing a custom plugin (interceptor).

The steps are mentioned below:

> **Step 1:** Create a file **app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/registration.php** and write below code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Stack_NewsletterRedirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **Step 2:** Create the **module.xml** under **app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/etc** folder and write below code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_NewsletterRedirect" setup_version="0.1.0"/>
</config>
```

> **Step 3:** Define the plugin for **Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction** in the **app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/etc/frontend/di.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction">
        <plugin name="redirect_after_newslettter" type="Stack\NewsletterRedirect\Plugin\Subscriber\Redirect"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Step 4:** Write the following code in the plugin file (**app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/Plugin/Subscriber/Redirect.php**):

```
<?php
namespace Stack\NewsletterRedirect\Plugin\Subscriber;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as responseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Redirect {

    public function __construct(
    responseHttp $response, UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction $subject, $result) {
        $url = $this->_url->getUrl('contact/index/index');
        $this->response->setRedirect($url);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Note:** You can change **`contact/index/index`** to any other page URL.

**Note:** Don't forget to run the following commands after creating above files:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a module with name **STech_Subscription** and create the files like below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Subscription/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Subscription',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Subscription/etc/module.xml

with below content:

**Step 3:**
Create **di.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Subscription/etc/frontend/di.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction" type="STech\Subscription\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction" />
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **NewAction.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Subscription/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Subscription\Controller\Subscriber;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface as CustomerAccountManagement;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{

    protected $customerAccountManagement;
    protected $_urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ) {
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        parent::__construct($context, $subscriberFactory, $customerSession, $storeManager, $customerUrl, $customerAccountManagement);

    }


    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

            try {
                $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
                if ($subscriber->getId()
                    && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
                ) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                    );
                }

                $status = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The confirmation request has been sent.'));
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException(
                    $e,
                    __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_urlInterface->getUrl('custom-thankyou')); // Edit tith your custom url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sukumar's solution worked for me. In step 2 the code for the file module.xml is not showing, but you can see it here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="STech_Subscription" setup_version="0.0.1">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
                <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

Comment: With the redirect there is no need for the default newsletter success message. Any idea how to disable it?